# Java scanner second input to narrow down searches

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am creating an interactive dictionary that will take external data sources from an enum class. I was able to create the dictionary successfully with a HashMap and the pairs operation to combine the type of speech to its definition. However, the program should narrow down the searches if a second input was entered. For example, "Distinct Noun" should output the nouns of distinct only. However, this only outputs both the values of Distinct and Noun. I tried creating a second scanner for the second input but when I do, the first input is not responsive. 
Does anyone know why this is happening? And can someone point me in the right direction?
I have tried scan.hasNextLine() and scan.next() but I am not sure if I am implementing them properly to narrow searches.

I provided a sample output of what I am getting and what is my desired output. If needed, I can provide my code but I would appreciate it if you guys/girls can just point me in the right direction as I would like to figure this out myself. 
Any information would be helpful.

Please let me know if I am asking this question improperly. This is my first post and I've heard stories of posting wrong questions or asking homework help is frowned upon. But I think asking for guidance is ok, right?

Thank you for your time,

My output:

```
Search: distinct noun
 |
   Distinct [adjective] : Familiar. Worked in Java.

   Distinct [adjective] : Unique, No duplicates.

   Distinct [adverb] : Unique. Written "distinctly".

   Distinct [noun] : A keyword in this assignment.

   Distinct [noun] : A keyword in this assignment.

   Distinct [noun] : A keyword in this assignment.

   Distinct [noun] : An advanced search option.

   Distinct [noun] : Distinct is a parameter in this assignment.
 |
 Search:  
 |
   Noun [noun] : Noun is a word that refers to a person, place, or thing.
 |
```

Desired output:

```
Search: distinct noun

 |

   Distinct [noun] : A keyword in this assignment.

   Distinct [noun] : A keyword in this assignment.

   Distinct [noun] : A keyword in this assignment.

   Distinct [noun] : An advanced search option.

   Distinct [noun] : Distinct is a parameter in this assignment.
 |
```

Here is my code:

```
public class DictionaryCSC340{

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList keyWords = new ArrayList();
    Map<String, List<dictionaryDataBase>> hmap = new HashMap<>();


    //Begin loading data
    System.out.println("! Loading data...");
    //Loop through data in dictionary
    for (dictionaryDataBase entry : dictionaryDataBase.values()) {      // Enhanced for-loop to get values from enum.

        ArrayList pairs = new ArrayList(); //ArrayList to store data speech and definition.

        String[] speech, definition;                 // Strings to store type and desc from enum
        keyWords.add(entry.name());          // Add all "Key names" to ArrayList
        speech = entry.getSpeech();            //string of speeches
        definition = entry.getDefinition();        //string of definitions


        //loop through speeches and pair it with its associated definitions.
        for (int i = 0; i < speech.length; i++) { 
            Pair<String, String> pair = new Pair<>(speech[i], definition[i]);   // Pair speech and definition   
            pairs.add(pair);    // Add pair with speech and definition to Arraylist "Pairs"
        }

        hmap.put(entry.name().toLowerCase(), pairs);       //Store entry names as the key value and speech and definitions as values. 

    }

    System.out.println("! Loading completed...");
    System.out.println("-----DICTIONARY 340 JAVA-----");


    //Interface properties
    ArrayList dataKey;        
    Pair inputPair;
    String input;


    //program begins search.
    do{

        System.out.print("Search: ");
        input = scan.next().toLowerCase();

        String entryName = new String();
        //Loop through keywords to find a match with the input (ignore cases)
        for(int i = 0; i < keyWords.size(); i++){
            if(((String) keyWords.get(i)).equalsIgnoreCase(input)){
                entryName = (String) keyWords.get(i);   
            }     
        }

        dataKey = (ArrayList) hmap.get(input);
        //if input matches with a value within HashMap, print its value.
        if(dataKey != null){
          System.out.println(" |");

          for(int i = 0; i < dataKey.size(); i++){
              inputPair =(Pair) dataKey.get(i);

              System.out.print("   " + entryName + " [" + inputPair.getKey() + "] : " );

              System.out.println(inputPair.getValue());
            }
          System.out.println(" |");

        }
        else if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("!Q")){  //exit operation when !Q is entered.
            System.out.println("-----THANK YOU-----");
            System.exit(0); 
        }
           //for words that are not within the database.
          else{
            System.out.println(" |");
            System.out.println("   <Not Found>");
            System.out.println(" |");
        }
    }
    while(true);
}
```

}

Comment: We can't help with specific coding problems unless you include the code and describe the specific problem you are having.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will provide a sample code

Comment: Sorry my post seems to need some editing to be more readable. I am fixing it right now